# Azure - My new azure account cannot access my resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

My azure admin e-mail account with godaddy, but for "reasons", this e-mail was deleted from godaddy server, with the problem solved, I was able to create a new account, with the same credentials that I had for azure admin, and it works, I can login into my azure account again, but, all my resources (apps, databases, services, etc) aren't being listed anymore, but they still working, now I have to do some maintenance and I can't access... Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you created a new subscription. Please call Azure support, create a ticket for them to move your resources from the old subscription to the new one.

Comment: Many thanks! Azure suport didn't told me that, I'm new at azure, i've done some research but I could'nt find this that you told me, please don't downvote me... =(

Comment: You are welcome! About voting, I up vote you, somebody else put you on -1.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you want to use a new account to reach the resources in the original subscription, your new account need to be in the same Tenant(Azure Active Directory) .

1. If you created the new account in the same Tenant (Azure AD), you can [**Add an RBAC Owner admin  to your account for a subscriptionin Azure portal**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).
2. If you created the new account in a different Tenant (Two accounts have different Azure AD), you need to [**add the new account as a guest user to your Directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b#you-can-easily-add-b2b-collaboration-users-to-your-organization) and then assign a Owner role to this account for the subscription.
   Assigning role to a guest user is same as the to an account in that directoy

By the way, if you is the owner of that subscription(who bought that subscription)  and also want to transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account, you can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer).